# Rails Mailkick Routes not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I've installed the gem (https://github.com/ankane/mailkick) and added the "unsubscribe" link.

```
<%= link_to "Unsubscribe", mailkick_unsubscribe_url %>
```

but when I click on the link in the email I have been redirected to

/mailkick?locale=en/subscriptions/BAhbCUkiHWNocmlzdGluYUBpdHNudXRmYWlyLmNvbQY6BkVUaRBJIglVc2VyBjsARjA=--fe51a96fa69c038b472c76328d726898859befba/unsubscribe?locale=en

where doesn't respond the mailkick route.

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/(:locale)' => 'pages#welcome'

  scope ":locale", locale: /en|it/ do 
   ...
  end 
end
```

I haven't found anything about mailkick in Routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like locale problem between Your project routes and mailkick gem routes. `/mailkick` endpoint might be attaching itself outside of locale scope.

You could try adding the same routes from the gem routes ([Source](https://github.com/ankane/mailkick/blob/master/config/routes.rb)) inside Your routes under `scope ":local"..`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/(:locale)' => 'pages#welcome'

  scope ":locale", locale: /en|it/ do 
    unless respond_to?(:has_named_route?) && has_named_route?("mailkick")
      mount Mailkick::Engine => "/mailkick" if Mailkick.mount
    end
    ...
  end 
end
```

Let me know if that perhaps fixes it?